# Reposition images within view based on size of text - iOS

Tags: ios, interface, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have been recently getting into iOS development, and I'm trying to build something that looks (very roughly) like this: http://falkendev.com/downloads/ios-sample.png

Basically, it's a page that shows simple text -- large header text that may span multiple lines, a separator line, and then smaller descriptive text that may be a variable length. This text does not need to be editable. I'm working using interface builder, but I imagine that what I want done may need to be done programmatically?

Two questions:

-- How do I go about creating these text fields so that they adjust their height based on the content? I'm assuming I would be using a standard "text" field for each, make them not editable, and then programmatically change their height? And then based on the height of the various text fields, I would need to adjust the positioning of the text fields and the divider line between them?

-- How do I go about making the page scrollable? It's possible that the descriptive text will be long and would extend off the edge of the screen. I would want the whole page to be scrollable, not just the descriptive text section. I'm assuming I would place all my elements within a scroll view... but currently when I do that and view it, the view just gets centered (cutting off both the top and the bottom) and I can't scroll it at all.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set the scrollview content size to greater than its actual size to
  make it scrollable like this :

  `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(YourWidth ,YourHEight ); // Here you can change either of height and width to make it more scrollable in that direction.`
- You can use `UITextView` object to have a scrollable text field...
  which can scroll to show additional text..just set its editing
  property to NO.
- Otherwise to dynamically update label height yourself...use

  `NSString sizeWithFont` method

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. In this case, I think I just had to stop overthinking things and just experiment till I got it.